# Any way to make Mac understand Windows file paths

Tags: windows, macos, filesystems, samba

My organisation use Windows almost exclusively, but I use a OSX for my work. Their intranet and many applications links to files on the org's Samba shares directly (e.g. "W:\Folder\File.ext")

Long shot, but is there a way I can force OSX to access the relative path on a mounted SMB volume? (e.g. "W:\Folder\File.ext" > "/Volumes/W/Folder/File.ext")

Comment: What filesystem does this SMB volume use?

Comment: @Ramhound What difference does it make? The filesystem of the share is completely hidden by the SMB layer AFAIK.

Answer (score -1):

Please see this similar question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22831/is-there-a-way-to-make-windows-style-smb-share-paths-launch-correctly

Also, I can highly recommend StExBar for Windows as a way to get people to copy network locations as UNC paths (not drive-letter paths).  If you could also get them to prefix the path when pasting to something like `smb://server/folder/file` (with the forward slashes), it should open up on your Mac, although I don't think that format will open in Windows.

So, in general, I recommend the solution in https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22831/is-there-a-way-to-make-windows-style-smb-share-paths-launch-correctly.

Comment: Answers should be self-contained, so they don't rely on other content being available and unchanged. The tip about using UNC paths may be helpful, but not if the whole organization has to change their habits and update documents for one person

Comment: Fairly certain we're allowed to reference other Stack sites in posts, without copying them here.  External content should be copied, yes, but I thought Stack was allowed?  Anyway, there's literally been no other answer for this almost 9 years, and the only suggestion gets downvoted?